# How to play raw YUV NV12 files on VLC Player

Tags: ios, objective-c, vlc, yuv

I am working with a video processing project which is developing on Objective C. Now, I got camera raw output in YUV(YpCbCr) format that is denoted as YUV(NV12) format. I have stored this output in a file. How can I play this raw YUV NV12 file on VLC player?

Another thing I should mention that, I could play raw YUV(I420) formatted video file on VLC by the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --demux rawvideo --rawvid-fps 10 --rawvid-width 640 --rawvid-height 480 --rawvid-chroma I420 input.yuv
```

Is it possible to play YUV(NV12) on vlc? 
Or, Is there any way to convert YUV(NV12) to YUV(I420) format?

Comment: I am also able to play raw YUV(420) format on MacOSX VLC by following Command
[ /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC --demux rawvideo --rawvid-fps 10 --rawvid-width 288 --rawvid-height 352 --rawvid-chroma I420 YuvTest.yuv ]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have also faced this kind of problem while working with YUV NV12 files. Traditional players like vlc, km or mpc can not play YUV NV12 files. But there I have found another player named **yuvplayer-2.3** which is able to play YUV-I420, YUV-444, YUV-UYVY, YUV-YUYV, YUV-NV12, YUV-NV21. You can download this player from this link:

-Download Link: http://skylink.dl.sourceforge.net/project/raw-yuvplayer/yuvplayer-2.3.zip

With this player you can easily play YUV-NV12 files.

Comment: You are right, I have also searched many contents to find a fruitful command to play raw YUV NV12 formatted files on vlc. But unfortunately I haven't found any options for --rawvid-chroma attribute to play NV12 files. There are many players like yuvplayer-2.3 is suitable to play raw video files.  I think yuvplayer-2.3 is one of the best options to play raw video files. Thanks for your hardwork. Thanks a lot.